# Why is the gesture of the rebel noble in "The Man with the Scar"?

Tags: short-stories, william-somerset-maugham

In the William Somerset Maugham short story ["The Man with the Scar"](https://kazhomereading.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/the-man-with-the-scar.pdf), the general considers the gesture of the rebel as a noble gesture. I don't understand why. He killed his love, the girl didn't kill herself, so why this murder is considered noble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revolutionary general's wife is young and beautiful. Since he is about to be executed for treason, her life is going to change a lot. She will likely be imprisoned or tortured to reveal what she knows about her husband's activities—e.g., other conspirators in the rebellion, etc.. As a woman, she is also vulnerable to sexual assault in this situation. To protect her from this harsh life, her husband murders her instead. A sexist and rather antiquated notion of honor, but one that prevailed in the time and place that this story is set.